# Can I use a chained payment in combination with 3-day capture?

Tags: paypal, payment, chained

User makes a request. Request may or not be fulfilled within 3 days.

If not, no payment processed. If yes, user payment processed and payment to primary receiver.

At a later date, the primary receiver will manually relinquish payment to the secondary receiver.

Can I use a delayed capture with the chained payment?  Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd need to use a [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) profile for the first part, and then you could hit the [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API within that 3 days and process the chained payment using the Preapproval key.  That would send the funds to the primary receiver, and then you'd use [ExecutePayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/) to trigger the secondary payments when you're ready to process them.